# Double click on nav selects div behind it even there is no text. How do I stop it?

Tags: jquery, html, selection, double-click

I have a slider with navigation arrows and when the arrow is double clicked, a `div` behind the `#slider1`, which is `.content-wrapper` gets selected like this:

http://gyazo.com/e66ab776b60455d8b496b46e3077099a

If arrow gets single click, it's ok, works like it should, but double click makes this weird selection. How can I stop this?

I already tried suggested here on stackoverflow methods like:

```
$('.arrow').dblclick(function(){
    return false;
});
```

and

```
$('.arrow').dblclick(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

and it didn't work.

Here is the html structure:

```
<div class="content-wrapper">
    <h2>Some long enough title</h2>
    <div class="red-divider" style="margin-bottom: 50px"></div>
    <div class="items">
        <div class="arrow left-small"></div>
        <div id="slider1">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="img/item1.png" height="59" width="72" alt="">
                        <p>Some product description text goes right here</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="img/item1.png" height="59" width="72" alt="">
                        <p>Some product description text goes right here</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="img/item1.png" height="59" width="72" alt="">
                        <p>Some product description text goes right here</p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="arrow right-small"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Arrows are obviously `.arrow left-small` and `.arrow right-small`.

Please tell me if I should post all jQuery code and CSS styles here.

Thank you.

EDIT:

Here is the CSS for all elements:

```
.content-wrapper {
width: 1080px;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0 28px;
position: relative;
}

.items {
margin: 0 auto;
}

#slider1 {
overflow: hidden;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#slider1 ul {
position: relative;
height: 124px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
list-style: none;
}

#slider1 ul li {
width: 320px;
position: relative;
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.item {
display: inline-block;
width: 300px;
vertical-align: top;
background-color: #fff;
border-radius: 5px;
padding: 30px 10px;
}

.arrow {
position: absolute;
top: 55%;
width: 27px;
height: 51px;
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 35px;
cursor: pointer;
z-index: 100;
}
```

`.left-small` sets background image and `left:`

EDIT2:

Also here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/55pewvb9/

EDIT3:

Here is the full page space-masters.com/samsung/

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
.arrow left-small {
z-index: 100;
}

.arrow right-small {
z-index: 100;
}
```

That should work...

If you want a more thought out answer, you should post all the css

Comment: Can You maybe post your css with a fiddle?

Comment: @nrvnm So clicking .arrow slides the #slider. Why would people even double click it? I dont know how your script is set up but, what happens if you put the .arrow outside of the #items div in html?

Comment: I tried moving `.arrow` outside of `.items` but it changed nothing. It is very easy to accidentally double click instead of doing a single click for people who are not too dexterous using the mouse or a delay between clicks for double click detection is too long. And when it happens on my page, that big blue selection looks weird and it doesn't go away on its own.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me. Instead of using div's for the arrows, try using anchors. They work better for click events and are a better fit semantically. Thus, change:

```
<div class="arrow left-small></a>
```

into:

```
<a class="arrow left-small></a>
```

Here is a working example, based on your HTML and CSS:

http://jsfiddle.net/uLnx4m77/2/

Comment: Thank you for the option @Tom but the selection is still going on.

Comment: I have a little trouble recreating your problem. You fiddle is too simple, and does not show the problem. The other link you provided is also problematic, even a single click does not work for me.